# why does multer works with png and jpg but not with webp on my configuration tsed, express, multer?

Tags: express, file-upload, multer, webp

My endpoint works for png and jpg.
I wanted to only allow webp, so I changed the file filter callback so it would be allowed.
However, it doesn't work with anything else than png or jpg : no error, multer sends me back an object that says it has successfully saved it on the specific path but on the disk there is nothing.

Why ?

here is my configuration object (it is specific to the tsed framework but I doubt it would be the issue, just a framework on top of express) > http://v4.tsed.io/tutorials/multer.html#installation

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
      let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
      let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uuidv4() + '.' +extension)
  }
})
```

```
  multer: {
    storage: storage,
    dest: `${process.cwd()}/uploads`,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 7340032,
    },
    fileFilter: (_req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
        // there was some condition here to check mimetype and throw an error if needed but I removed it for testing with other mimetypes
        return cb(null, true);
    }
  }
```

and my endpoint looks like this :

```
  @Post("/photo")
  @Authorize("jwt") @Security("jwt")
  @Returns(200) 
  @Returns(401) 
  @Returns(404)
  private async simpleUpload(
    @MultipartFile("file") 
    file: PlatformMulterFile) {
    if (!file) {
      throw new NotFound('file not found');
    }
    console.log(file);
    return{filename : file.filename}
  }
```

I am really confused because I always get a 200 response and the console.log output looks like this :

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'pauline.pdf',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/pdf',
  destination: './uploads',
  filename: 'file-f6219302-1491-47f0-b10f-883fdc6ef15a.pdf',
  path: 'uploads/file-f6219302-1491-47f0-b10f-883fdc6ef15a.pdf',
  size: 12033
}
```

or

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'mouse_logo.svg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
  destination: './uploads',
  filename: 'file-138c1a1f-9b80-4f6c-b474-dfd25afaaf50.svg+xml',
  path: 'uploads/file-138c1a1f-9b80-4f6c-b474-dfd25afaaf50.svg+xml',
  size: 1076
}
```

In both cases, no error but also no file on the disk. With exactly the same configurations, png and jpg files are uploaded and the file appears. If anyone would have a lead I would be much interested ._.

Answer (score 0):

No error in the server configuration. I just forgot that I had a bash script that automatically deletes anything that wasn't a png / jpg on the upload folder.